# How to call new JSON AsynTask() in the Adapter's getView() on CheckBox click?

Tags: android, json, checkbox, adapter, getview

I know the JSON parsing. I have A `ListView` and `GridView` in same `Activity`. My `ListView` has Check Box. So I am getting it's click in adapter class. So when I check that Check Box, then A new JSON will call and the data will set in the `GridView`. But when I am trying to call the new JSON on `setOnCheckedChangeListener()`. then I am getting

> “System services not available to Activities before onCreate()”  in
>   onPostExecute().

Here is my code.

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {

                    ac = new PhoneAndTabletsActivity();
                     ac.new SendFilterInfo().execute();


                }
            });
```

In `postExecute()`

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        phoneTabletAdapter = new PhoneAndTabletAdapter1(
                PhoneAndTabletsActivity.this,
                R.layout.row_phone_and_tablet1, filterArray);
        gridView.setAdapter(phoneTabletAdapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if **PhoneAndTabletsActivity** your main activity your should not create new activity

remove this

```
ac = new PhoneAndTabletsActivity();
                     ac.new SendFilterInfo().execute();
```

is used only `new SendFilterInfo().execute();`

Comment: As I remove this then I got this error message "No enclosing instance of type PhoneAndTabletsActivity is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type PhoneAndTabletsActivity (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of PhoneAndTabletsActivity)."

Comment: SendFilterInfo class is child of PhoneAndTabletsActivity? that is invested